# Is there any alternative way for trigger in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to run the pipeline in azure data factory without using trigger.
So Is there any service which we can use instead of trigger in Azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ADF, every pipeline will be executed by manual or by trigger.

The alternative way to ADF triggers can be done by following.

1. By Powershell.
2. Logic app.
3. Using [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelines/create-run?tabs=HTTP).

**By Powershell:**

Use [Invoke-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.datafactoryv2/invoke-azurermdatafactoryv2pipeline?view=azurermps-6.13.0) or [Invoke-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.datafactory/invoke-azdatafactoryv2pipeline?view=azps-8.2.0) in Powershell.

Command:

```
Invoke-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Pipeline -ResourceGroupName "RG name" -DataFactoryName "rakeshdfactory" -PipelineName "MyADFpipeline"
```

You will get the Pipeline run id in Powershell after executing and you can see the pipeline run in Monitor pipelines-> Trigger runs of ADF.

[image]

[image]

Schedule this Powershell script using Azure Automation to execute the pipeline daily.

Reference:

[Third party tutorial to learn about powershell automation from sharepointdairy by Salaudeen Rajack](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2020/11/sharepoint-online-schedule-powershell-script-using-azure-automation.html)

**Using Logic apps:**

ADF event triggers are only permitted to storage accounts, but logic apps can give other options like SQL tables as well.

Here I have created a blob trigger for the logic app. You can create **Recurrence trigger** for the logic app instead of blob trigger, by which you can schedule the logic app to invoke the ADF pipeline.

[image]

[image]

Reference:

[Article by MITCHELL PEARSON](https://mitchellpearson.com/2020/05/11/azure-data-factory-executing-an-adf-pipeline-from-azure-logic-apps/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean without using the Trigger definitions inside Data Factory, then yes [there are other options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azuredatafactory/). The two that I use almost exclusively are 1) Logic Apps and 2) the [Azure Data Factory SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/data-factory) ([this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-create-data-factories-programmatically) may also be useful). I use a Function App to house my SDK code, and in most cases I have Logic Apps call the AF instead of executing the pipeline directly.

NOTE: purely for pedantic purposes, every pipeline run has a Trigger. When you execute by using the *Trigger Now* feature inside the workspace or execute a pipeline externally using one of the above methods, the Trigger Type will show as "Manual" in the Monitor section.